# many to many relation that store different objects id_s in differen object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database

Hi I want to create a relation in Rails.

I have warrior model, mage model and faction model.

I want to create a relation like this:

```
warrior model can have_many factions 
mage model can have many factions. 
Faction model can have many warriors and mages
```

**How can I create relation between warriors and mages objects and faction object, that will store id_s of both warriors and mages that belong to specific faction/factions ?**

So when I call:

```
 faction.warriors I get warriors of specific faction. 
 faction.mage I get mages of this faction
 warriors.faction I get the warrior faction.
 mage.faction I get the mage faction.
```

I was thinking about polymorphic association. But it has only one owner.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I create relation between warriors and mages objects and faction object, that will store id_s of both warriors and mages that belong to specific faction/factions ?

With [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) relationships

```
Warrior
  has_and_belongs_to_many :factions

Mage
  has_and_belongs_to_many :factions

Faction
  has_and_belongs_to_many :mages
  has_and_belongs_to_many :warriors
```

Comment: I mark this as correct, but in the end I used has_many though. But this answer is still correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear whether you want a many_to_many or has_many relationship.

But from what you wrote here:

> faction.warriors I get warriors of specific faction. 
>   faction.mage I get mages of this faction
>   warriors.faction I get the warrior faction.
>   mage.faction I get the mage faction.

It appears that all you need is a simple association. If that's correct your classes should look like this:

```
class Warrior < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :faction
end

class Mage < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :faction
end

class Faction < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :warriors
    has_many :mages
end
```

Cheers!